# C multiple definition error Netbeans

Tags: c, java-native-interface, multiple-definition-error

I'm trying to build some native libraries in C that will speed up the monte-carlo simulation for a Java project. I'm doing this on Netbeans 7.0.1, using MINGW

I'm using the mtwist source code of Geof Kuenning (http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/emt.html) to provide Mersenne Twister pseudorandom numbers.

I have three different models to simulate, and each compiles fine on its own (with output to file rather than using the JNI). However, when I combine the three models under the JNI header file, I start to get a long list of errors when I try to build:

> CLEAN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 7s)
>   "/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
>   make[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Tom/Documents/LongMemoryModels/longMemModels'
>   "/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW_1- Windows/liblongMemModels.dll
>   make[2]: Entering directory`/c/Users/Tom/Documents/LongMemoryModels/longMemModels'
>   mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows
>   rm -f build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/longmem.o.d
>   gcc.exe -std=c99   -c -g -I../../../../../Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.7.0/include/ -I../../../../../Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.7.0/include/win32  -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/longmem.o.d -o build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/longmem.o longmem.c
>   mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/_ext/2069311947
>   rm -f build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/_ext/2069311947/mtwist.o.d
>   gcc.exe -std=c99   -c -g -I../../../../../Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.7.0/include/ -I../../../../../Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.7.0/include/win32  -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/_ext/2069311947/mtwist.o.d -o build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/_ext/2069311947/mtwist.o ../../../../../cinclude/mtwist/mtwist.c
>   mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/_ext/2069311947
>   rm -f build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/_ext/2069311947/randistrs.o.d
>   gcc.exe -std=c99   -c -g -I../../../../../Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.7.0/include/ -I../../../../../Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.7.0/include/win32  -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/_ext/2069311947/randistrs.o.d -o build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/_ext/2069311947/randistrs.o ../../../../../cinclude/mtwist/randistrs.c
>   mkdir -p dist/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows
>   gcc.exe -std=c99    -shared -o dist/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/liblongMemModels.dll build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/longmem.o build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/_ext/2069311947/mtwist.o > build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/_ext/2069311947/randistrs.o
>   build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/_ext/2069311947/mtwist.o: In function `mts_lrand':
>   C:\Users\Tom\Documents\LongMemoryModels\longMemModels/../../../../../cinclude/mtwist/mtwist.h:402: multiple definition of`mts_lrand'
>   build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/longmem.o:C:/cinclude/mtwist/mtwist.h:402: first defined here
>   build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/_ext/2069311947/mtwist.o: In function `mts_llrand':
>   C:\Users\Tom\Documents\LongMemoryModels\longMemModels/../../../../../cinclude/mtwist/mtwist.h:431: multiple definition of`mts_llrand'
>   build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/longmem.o:C:/cinclude/mtwist/mtwist.h:431: first defined here
>   [...]
>   build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/_ext/2069311947/randistrs.o: In function `mts_lrand':
>   C:\Users\Tom\Documents\LongMemoryModels\longMemModels/../../../../../cinclude/mtwist/mtwist.h:402: multiple definition of`mts_lrand'
>   build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/longmem.o:C:/cinclude/mtwist/mtwist.h:402: first defined here
>   build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/_ext/2069311947/randistrs.o: In function `mts_llrand':
>   C:\Users\Tom\Documents\LongMemoryModels\longMemModels/../../../../../cinclude/mtwist/mtwist.h:431: multiple definition of`mts_llrand'
>   build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/longmem.o:C:/cinclude/mtwist/mtwist.h:431: first defined here
>   [...]
>   make[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Tom/Documents/LongMemoryModels/longMemModels'
>   make[1]: Leaving directory`/c/Users/Tom/Documents/LongMemoryModels/longMemModels'
>
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/liblongMemModels.dll] Error 1
>   make[1]:**  [.build-conf] Error 2
>   make: ** [.build-impl] Error 2
>
> BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 22s)

(here the elipsis, [...], denotes similar errors that I have omitted)

As you can see, the multiple inclusions seem to relate to the mtwist.h header rather than the JNI header. Moreover, I get the same errors trying to build the JNI project even when mtwist has already been successfully built as a static or dynamic library...

I don't want this question to be too much of an essay, and I'm hoping that error will reveal an obvious error to someone more savvy than me. BUT, I'll post source code too, if this isn't enough to point to a solution.

Please help me resolve this build error if you can.
Tom

EDIT: to make the include structure clearer than in the comments...
In the current arrangement:

- [JNI models header].h includes jni.h
- mtwist.h includes stdio.h, stdint.h
- randistrs.h, includes mtwist.h
- [individual model functions].c includes stdio.h stdlib.h math.h mtwist/mtwist.h mtwist/randistrs.h jni.h (unnecessary I suppose)
- mtwist.c includes inttypes.h stdio.h stdlib.h sys/timeb.h mtwist.h
- randistrs.c includes mtwist.h randistrs.h math.h stdlib.h

All of the .h files have inclusion guards using #ifndef

Comment: multipe definition error appears when two (or more) variables/functions have the exact same name in a scope. Are you sure your three models are made to be compiled together?

Comment: thanks MisterJ, but the three models are very simple - each consists of only a single function, and each function has a distinct name. What's more, I get the same build errors whether all three functions are listed in the same .c file or are in separate files with separate includes.

Comment: Sounds like multiple inclusion. Exactly which files are included where, starting at your main file?

Comment: So, in the current arrangement:
[JNI models header].h includes <jni.h>;   

mtwist.h includes <stdio.h> <stdint.h>;   

randistrs.h includes "mtwist.h";   


[individual model functions].c includes <stdio.h> <stdlib.h> <math.h> <mtwist/mtwist.h> <mtwist/randistrs.h> <jni.h> (unnecessary I suppose);   

mtwist.c includes <inttypes.h> <stdio.h> <stdlib.h> <sys/timeb.h><mtwist.h>;   

randistrs.c includes "mtwist.h" "randistrs.h" <math.h> <stdlib.h>;   

All of the .h files have inclusion guards using #ifndef

Answer (score 0):

i guess it's a case of multiple inclusion of prototype.Please try guarding using #ifdef #endif Macro in mtwist.h, for all those prototypes which are giving error.

Comment: thanks Dayal, but mtwist.h starts out with #ifndef MTWIST_H
#define MTWIST_H . Shouldn't this be enough to guard against multiple inclusions?